# How can I group the data in an array or JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have a NODE script where I download some information that I need to "reparse", first it downloads a .txt, then I convert it to a CSV then to JSON and then I convert it to an XML, I do it this way since going from .txt to XML is impossible.

The problem is the JSON returns me an object similar to this:

```
  [{
    "id": "3435",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "3436",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "343534",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "343345",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "3433435",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    }]
```

I would like to group them by "product" like this

```
{
"root" : {
    "item": {
        "id": 3435,
        "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
        "PriceProducto" : "19.000",
    },
    "item": {
        "id": 3436,
        "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
        "PriceProducto" : "19.000",
    },
    "item": {
        "id": 34334,
        "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
        "PriceProducto" : "19.000",
    },
    "item": {
        "id": 343345,
        "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
        "PriceProducto" : "19.000",
    },
    "item": {
        "id": 3433455,
        "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
        "PriceProducto" : "19.000",
    }

}}
```

If you have a solution for this I would be very grateful!

Comment: Without understanding the output of the previous steps it's difficult to help you since that output JSON is invalid, and can't be parsed and manipulated. It would need to be the text or CSV conversion that would need to be changed.

Comment: Both JSON objects are wrong, because they overwrite the same properties. So only the last of each property will exist after parsing.

Comment: Following what @GabrielePetrioli commented: Is the requirement to have the data in this non-JSON format or would it be acceptable to format the output as JSON?

Comment: hello sorry how I put that JSON, now if I edited how I actually get the JSON

Comment: @MoisesPachon ... _"I would like to group them by 'product' like this"_ ... which **product** related property should it be? Because so far there is nothing called or related to a `'product'` key; there are just `'nameProducto'` and `'PriceProducto'`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it's not possible in json/objects to generate the 'root' object with multiple keys named 'item'.

Below is an approach that could work using the index of the array of products in the keys of the object:

```js
const inputJson =  [{
    "id": "3435",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "3436",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "343534",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "343345",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    },
    {
    "id": "3433435",
    "nameProducto" : "Nombre del producto",
    "PriceProducto" : "19.000"
    }]
    
 let outputJson = { "root" : {}}
 
 inputJson.forEach((item,index) => {
  outputJson.root[`item_${index}`] ={
    item
  }
  
})

console.log(outputJson)
```

Comment: Generated keys, especially with a fixed word-stem and an incremented counter-value are a strong indicator for actually wanting to store such items into an array as it already happens with the OP's original data-structure. Also the sole nested `item` property per generated/incremented entry is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how could I generate the object without the [`item_${index}`]? I don't really know if this could be possible, this is one of the outputs " item_10059: { item: [Object] }"